# STL: Processing two collections without an output

Tags: c++, stl

If one wishes to process elements of two collections into a third collection, STL transform algorithm can be used:

```
// elements of x,y are multiplied, result is in r
std::transform(x.begin(),x.end(), w.begin(), back_inserter(r), [](int _x,int _w){return _x*_w;});
```

What if only the sum of r elements is needed? In the following solution the creation of r is redundant:

```
int xwSum = 0;
std::transform(x.begin(),x.end(), w.begin(), back_inserter(r), [&xwSum](int _x,int _w){xwSum+=_x*_w; return 0;});
```

There must be a better solution, any ideas?

Comment: `std::accumulate` is created exactly for this purpose

Comment: Are you looking for http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce?

Comment: [std::inner_product](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product)

Comment: Actually I did not read code and OP's description is confusing, looks like `std::inner_product()` is what he needs.

Comment: std::accumulate works on one collection. It is possible to use transform and then accumulate the result. I wonder, however, if there is a way to do this in one pass. My second example performs this in one pass, but has the unwanted side effect of creating unnecessary collection which I wish to eliminate.

Comment: You should consider looking at the cppitertools library: https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools. It lets you do many cool things in similar style to python. In this case you could use zip to iterate over two collections in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::inner_product`, it does exactly what you want:

```
int res = std::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), w.begin(), 0);
```

Runnable version: https://ideone.com/zXcO2y